# How do you escape a semicolon in COMPILE_FLAGS property of cmake?

Tags: visual-c++, preprocessor, escaping, cmake

I need to get this as a result in the preprocessor definitions of the msvc generator:

```
MYPATH=\"d:\\;.\\Lib\"
```

But when I use the following escape sequence in set_source_files_properties:

```
set_source_files_properties(source.c PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-DMYPATH=\\\"d:\\\;.\\\\Lib\\\"")
```

the generated result is: **MYPATH=\"d:\";".\Lib\"**

Note the double-quoted semicolon. Is there a quoting workaround to allow unquoted semicolons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIR, cmake treat ; as list separator, so it behaves in such way for properties as per documentation.

PROPERTY  [value1 [value2 ...]

Probably you've better to try something like this - make it string variable and then try substitute it.

```
set(MY_PATH "\"d:\\\;.\\\\Lib\\\"")
set_source_files_properties(source.c PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS ${MY_PATH})
```

HTH,
Sergey